# Arbitrary ordering of Django objects

Tags: python, django, sequence

Say I have series of book chapter objects, defined by this model:

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField()
    contents = models.TextField()
```

And suppose I currently have four chapters: a, b, c, and d. How would I define the order of the chapters to be b, d, c, a or some other arbitrary sequence?

Comment: The most generic way is to add integer field, and do ordering by it.

Comment: -1 Why? this is a good question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you will be pretty happy with the `order-with-respect-to` Django Meta option.

Just take a look at the [Meta options reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to)

I couldn't find a way to use any other field than the `id` in `set_RELATED_order`.
It occured to me, though I did not test it, that you could have a `order = IntegerField...` in your Chapter model, and have a statement that looks something like this somewhere:

```
order = [id for (order, id) in sorted([(x.order, x.id) for x in Chapter.objects.all()], key=0)]
```

I'm not being precise nor reliably here. I'm just trying to point you a direction with a reference [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to) and an insight.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could:

1. **Add a 'sortkey'** integer field to the Chapter model,
2. **Set the sortkey for each model**, that means 1 for the chapter you want first, 2 for the second, etc, etc ...
3. **Set [Chapter.Meta.ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering)**, so that the sortkey will be use for default ordering

It would look like:

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    heading = models.CharField()
    contents = models.TextField()
    sortkey = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('sortkey',)
```

Comment: So if I've assigned sortkeys to my chapters (e.g., a=0, b=1, c=2, d=3), what is the best way to change the order?

Comment: @JosephMornin By assinging other values.

Answer (score -1):

Those solutions are a horror!!

```
Chapter.objects.all().order_by("?")
```

Very very simple and pretty